# Get property of non-object in

Tags: php, postgresql, yii

I am doing a test project using pgsql database with yii php. 
on Controller page I'm trying to get and table row:

```
$dbCon = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=dbname user=postgres password=root");
$row = pg_query_params($dbCon, 'SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE id = $1', array($id));
```

I'm getting an error 'Trying to get property of non-object in'.

Comment: It seems to be the case that these are not the lines reported in your error msg.

Comment: My point is $row is empty. Error says, "Trying to get property of non-object (C:\wamp\www\project\server\protected\controllers\ReportingController.php:1026)".

Comment: Only a few possible reasons. Your db conn failed or your query is buggy or your query returns an empty result. You need to check for all of these and enable error reporting for debugging

Comment: Everything is ok. Here I did not execute the query so it didn't fetch the record from database. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I did a mistake here. At $row I just create the query and it still didn't execute. So I added few line:

```
 $query = pg_query_params($dbCon, 'SELECT * FROM hq6k2_device d WHERE d.id = $1', array($id));
 $row = 0;
 $data = pg_fetch_object($query, $row);
```

And now i have my wanted result. It's just a silly mistake.